# How can I 'hide' built in classes when I have written my own wrappers to said classes?

Tags: c#, class, namespaces, system

I'm writing a fairly large library with a compliment of either classes that I've designed myself, or wrappers for lower-level system classes.

An instance of this would be something like a StreamReader or a StreamWriter. This fact is irrelevant, but I've written a wrapper that is capable of creating a thread for each of these and reading ( for instance ) continuously - for use in something like a TcpClient.

Jargon and irrelevant information aside - the question here is, is there a way to 'hide' built in members of a system namespace, with my own inherited class?

I understand how namespaces work, and that I can reference 'Namespace.Subspace.Class' when I have ambiguous references, but I wonder if there is any way to automatically 'prefer' my class over the one from the system.

Hope I've been explicit enough in what I'm asking; if anyone has asked it in the past, I extend my apologies for re-asking it. Hope there's an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way for you to "override" classes in other assemblies.

If you could it would be a bad design element IMHO. If I want to use your special wrapper I will call a instance of your special wrapper, otherwise I want the behavior and known side effects of the class I intended to call.

Comment: Well then... Fair enough. Thanks for the information. On a personal note... I feel like if you're going to provide an answer and not criticize the question, you should upvote it... It was a complete question with all of the necessary information. Sorry; I just ask a lot of questions that get no votes, even though they're previously unasked an generally thorough. Regardless; thanks for the info. Cheers.

Comment: Your question did not show research effort, to me it seemed that asking the question SO was the research effort, that is why I did not up-vote. Stack Overflow should be your last resort, not your first. I highly recommend you read over [The Stack Overflow Question Checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), If you start having your questions follow that checklist you will receive more up-votes.

Comment: Entitlement is an ugly face. I'm not going to spend an hour sifting through search results that tell me how to make a class in its own namespace, or how to override a class in general, because my topic is actually rather obscure, just to find something that tells me I can't do what I was hoping; when I can ask here and have an answer in minutes. Besides the fact that it has never been asked. You're welcome to your opinion I suppose; but if you can find a website anywhere that tells me that this can't be done in less than twenty minutes, I'd be impressed.

Comment: Perhaps you should Downvote the question if you feel it lacks research. That is the intent.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem obvious, but not including "using System.IO;" at the top of the file and instead including "using MyClasses.MyIOWrapper;" may help.  This way it will use your implementation of StreamReader, etc instead of the system's, unless you explicitly tell it to use the system's.

Comment: A more valid answer than the above - thank you for the thought - but this was the obvious solution - until I realize that I have other uses from System.IO.

Comment: Right, there is no easy way to do this since all the system classes are sealed.  But you still have access to the System.IO classes, it just takes a little extra typing since you have to type System.IO.Whatever, but it's not really that bad since intellisense will fill most of it in for you.